# "Полгода" — какое число?

Tags: согласование

На одном ресурсе попался интересный вопрос. Хотелось бы услышать мнение специалистов. "Эти полгода значат для меня очень много". Автоматически пишешь во множественном числе "полгода — значат". Но почему так? Полгода — единичный промежуток времени.

Comment: Наверно, потому что подразумеваем 6 месяцев.

Comment: Но ведь "год" — это единственное число, а подразумевается еще больше — 12 месяцев)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Слова с "пол" независимо от значения грамматически относятся к множественному числу:
эти пол-лимона, эти полгорода, эти полведра, эти полчаса и т.д. Исключение: "поллитра" в занчении "бутылка водки".